# How can i search some letters in a word in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

in shell run.sh i have

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec grep -H SNR {} \; | grep "$1" > result.txt
if[ "$1" -eq "offs0.5"] 
 then 
 fi
```

if i enter: `run.sh offs0.5`

this error:

> [: offs0.5 : integer expression expected

Comment: What are trying to do exactly? You need to have a space between `"offs0.5"` and `]`, and you need to use the `==` operator for testing two strings.

Comment: `-eq` is a numeric operator. Maybe you mean `=`? Explain what you're trying to do with some sample input and expected output and we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

To make a string comparison you need to use something like:

```
[ "$1" == "offs0.5" ]
```

Note that your expression with `eq` is looking for an arithmetic comparison, while you are comparing strings.

Also, in your expression you have

```
if[ "$1" -eq "offs0.5"] 
          ^^^        ^ needed space
          no eq on string comparison
```

#### Test

```
$ d="offs0.5"
$ 
$ [ "$d" == "offs0.5" ] && echo "yes"
yes

$ d="offs0.5aa"
$ [ "$d" == "offs0.5" ] && echo "yes"
```